# Detecting successful channel join in IRC with Java

Tags: java, join, bots, irc

A friend and I (well a friend w/ me looking over the code to find any logical inconsistencies) are trying to write an IRC bot in Java mostly from scratch (that is, not using egg drop or other popular starting points). It's rather easy to detect a successful server join (socket.isConnected()), but I'm trying to figure out a way to detect a successful channel join. Basically, instead of just assuming that the join was successful, I want to be able to read from the server if the nick is moderated or banned or something else which prevents channel joining. Thanks!

Basically I want to be able to print out "Channel __ joined" if successful or "Channel ___ join failed" if the join wasn't successful. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks!

Edit: Upon further research, I'm now interested in learning how to decipher server message codes, specifically the format in which they're sent back to the client. Thanks!

Comment: You can parse all messages from the server quite easily, as they all follow the same format. If the first character is a colon (`:`), then there's a "from" section to the message, ending at the first space. Then, a command (word or numeric) followed by space-separated arguments (unless there's a space-colon - ` :` - in which case the character after the colon to the end is the final argument). In my library, I encapsulate all this into a class for easy handling by the rest of the code.

Comment: Add that as an answer please. Jack's numeric replies link plus your explanation made the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading through the RFC, particularly the [JOIN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-3.2.1) command and the [numeric replies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-5). The [Messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-2.3) section explains the basics of sending messages back and forth. You should probably try to understand a protocol before you try to implement it though ;)

Comment: I understand how it works generally, I'm more concerned with how to parse the server's reply. Thanks for the numeric replies link though! Now, to figure out how to use it.

Comment: If you're interested in actual parsing, I've found [JavaCC](https://java.net/projects/javacc) to work well in Java :) good luck

Comment: If I could up yours twice I would, since JavaCC would do the trick, although I implemented my own parser.